# Room database Livedata getValue() returns null

Tags: android, viewmodel, dao, android-room, android-livedata

I was trying to fetch a list of custom object data from room using LiveData and viewmodel. While using Livedata's getValue() method, returns null but getting list directly shows the actual data. How can I get List of Period class using LiveData in viewmodel class.

> Entity classes

```
@Entity
public class Period {

@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
String header;
@TypeConverters(WritterConverter.class)
ArrayList<Writter> writters;

public Period(String header, ArrayList<Writter> writters) {
    this.header = header;
    this.writters = writters;
}

public String getHeader() {
    return header;
}

public ArrayList<Writter> getWritters() {
    return writters;
}


}

@Entity
public class Writter {

String birth;
String death;
String name;
ArrayList<String> novels;

public Writter(){}

public Writter(String birth, String death, String name, ArrayList<String> novels) {
    this.birth = birth;
    this.death = death;
    this.name = name;
    this.novels = novels;
}

public String getBirth() {
    return birth;
}

public String getDeath() {
    return death;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public ArrayList<String> getNovels() {
    return novels;
}
}
```

> Converter Class

```
public class WritterConverter {

@TypeConverter
public static ArrayList<Writter> fromString(String value){
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Writter>>(){}.getType();
    return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
}

@TypeConverter
public static String fromArrayList(ArrayList<Writter> list){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    return json;
}

}
```

> DAO class

```
@Dao
@TypeConverters({WritterConverter.class})
public interface DAO {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertPeriod(Period period);

@Query("SELECT * FROM Period WHERE header LIKE :header")
Period getPeriodList(String header);

@Query("SELECT * FROM Period")
LiveData<List<Period>> getAllPeriodList();

}
```

> Database

```
@Database(version = 1, entities = {Period.class})
public abstract class MyDatabase extends RoomDatabase{

static MyDatabase databaseInstance;

public static MyDatabase getDatabaseInstance(Context context) {
    if (databaseInstance == null)
        databaseInstance = Room
                .databaseBuilder(context, MyDatabase.class, "testDatabase1")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                //     .addMigrations(FROM_1_TO_2)
                .build();

    return databaseInstance;
}

abstract public DAO dao();



}
```

> Get Data method in viewmodel class

```
 private void getDataFromDatabase() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, LiveData<List<Period>>>() {
        @Override
        protected LiveData<List<Period>> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            LiveData<List<Period>> periodList = MyApplication.getDatabase().dao().getAllPeriodList();
          //  Period periodList = MyApplication.getDatabase().dao().getWriterList(EndPoints.THE_OLD_ENGLISH_PERIOD);
            return periodList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(LiveData<List<Period>> aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
         //  Period period = aVoid.getValue().get(0);
            Log.d("header", aVoid.getValue().get(0).getHeader());
        }
    }.execute();

}
```

Comment: do not use `AsyncTask`and `LiveData.getValue()` ... use `LiveData.observe()`

Comment: `new AsyncTask<Void, Void, LiveData<List<Period>>>() {` where did you get this idea? I'm pretty sure this is not how it's described in the https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#13

Comment: According to documentation I thought the fetch operation should be called in async, that's why I did the mistake. By the way, thank you all for clearing my idea.

Comment: Should we continue using `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is,

1. `Asynctask` is running on another thread in background **asynchronously**
2. `Livedata` is working like floating over database to see the changes.

So it takes time to accomplish the fetch operation for `Asyntask`. You can see it by testing the `Asynctask` within a handler of 10 sec delay.
So its better to directly call the fetch operation in view model and send it to activity/fragment as livedata.observe.

Comment: Great, I have tested with handler and it was real. Thanks again for explaining. Got a better view of room operation along with asynctask.

Comment: @Razon but please refrain from using handler, just as Hossain said pass the livedata to your view class and observe it

Comment: @keivan, I told to use handler only for testing to see what actually happens.

Answer (score 12):

Usually `Room` handle queries **Synchronously** but using it along `LiveData` these queries get execute in an **ASynchronous** manner, so when you call this line:

```
LiveData<List<Period>> periodList = MyApplication.getDatabase().dao().getAllPeriodList();
```

, you actually get an **empty** container which will get **updated** after the query is executed and completed. So to get the result of the query or even for the query to get **executed** in the first place, you must **observe** the returned `LiveData`.

Now the usual scenario is to just **pass** the `LiveData` that `Room` provides from **ViewModel** to your **View** and then observe the `LiveData` for changes in **View**.

Inside **ViewModel**:

```
public LiveData<List<Period>> getAllPeriods() {
    return MyApplication.getDatabase().dao().getAllPeriodList();
}
```

Inside **View**:

```
viewModel.getAllPeriods().observe(this, new Observer<List<Period>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Period> periods) {
        updateList(periods); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, now it's totally clear to me.

Comment: @Razon your welcome, I provided code sample too, hope it helps